# Multiple Offers from Amazon Products API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been working recently with the Amazon Products API, and I had a question for anyone out there with experience using it. Is it possible using one of the responseGroups to get a full listing of all offers in the Amazon marketplace?

For example, one product might have 37 offers in the marketplace, but in every API call I've performed, I never seem to be able to get anything other than the Amazon.com price and the price of the lowest cost marketplace item.

Is there any way to get all 37 offers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  I use the ItemLookup operation and with that I use the ResponseGroup "OfferFull".  That will return up to 10 offers.  You'll have to loop to get the next set of offers until you've got them all.

In the Offers object (inside ItemLookupResponse that you get back), you'll see a property called "TotalOfferPages" that will tell you how many pages of 10 offers.  Just put a check inside a loop for this value and accumulate the Offers into a collection.

Amazon Documentation:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/

If you use C# and want to use WCF, read this:

http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/

Hope this helps,
Scott

Comment: This feature was removed in end of 2011.